# how to get date difference

Tags: php, laravel-5

In laravel i am using this :

```
@php
 $ids = Session::get('id');
 $res = DB::table('user')
       ->select('dates as date')
       ->where('id','=',$user_id)
       ->get();
$date_time=$res[0]->date;
$date = new DateTime($date_time);
$now = date('Y-m-d');
$dayss_left=$date->diff($now)->format("%d");
@endphp

//In $date_time i am getting :"2018-06-28"
//And In $now getting:        "2018-02-25"
```

Its returning me erroe like:

```
DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

What i am doing wrong here can anyone please  tell i want days only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string from [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). You could create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
new DateTime($now)
```

You could update your code to:

```
$dayss_left=$date->diff(new DateTime($now))->format("%d");
```

To create a DateTime in a specific format, you use [createfromformat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_time);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I think the code itself works [in this example](https://3v4l.org/H7gRs).
Can you check if `$res[0]` exists and  `res[0]->date` exists? `vardump($res[0])` or `var_dump(res[0]->date)`

Comment: see if $date_time = "2018-06-22"; then its returning 5 days ... why

Comment: after var_dump its $res[0]->date.   returning "20018-11-02" and $res->date returning error trying to get object

Comment: Try it with [createfromformat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) like [this example](https://3v4l.org/3W6AM)

Comment: I have updated my answer. "20018-11-02"? or do you mean "2018-11-02". Yo might check that.